# One of this three codes is not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to find out what is wrong in this program (C code). But I don't get anything clear. I'd appreciate some help. I get this error `main.c:10:11: error: lvalue required as increment operand`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 100

main()
{   int j;
    float P[MAXIMUM];

    for (j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++) {
         *P = 0.0;
         P++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't wipe out your question like that.

Answer (score 2):

array types and pointer types are not same even though they work similarly in many situations. You cannot change where an array points to. You cannot increment it or decrement it like you can with a pointer.

Use:

```
for (j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++) {
     P[j] = 0.0;
}
```

If you want use a pointer, you can create a pointer that points to the array and then increment it.

```
float* ptr = P;
for (j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++) {
     *ptr = 0.0;
     ptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pointer (as you have now) in the `for` loop, you should declare something like:

```
float P_array[MAXIMUM];
float *P = P_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

First just to highlight...

Do not use...

```
main()
```

Use

```
int main(void)
```

Second... You created an array, not a pointer which was *P

Do this instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 100

int main(void)
{   int j;
    float P[MAXIMUM]; // Create array

    for (j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++) //First loop, j = 0. Second loop, j = 1
    {
         P[j] = 0.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to print results

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXIMUM 100

int main(void)
{   int j;
    float P[MAXIMUM]; // Create array

    for (j = 0; j < MAXIMUM; j++) //First loop, j = 0. Second loop, j = 1
    {
         P[j] = 0.0;
         printf("%d: %d", j, P[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```